# minimize system of infinity norm of polynomials

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, np-complete

I have a problem that looks like this:
set of expressions of the form:
$p_i = ax_{i}+bx_{i}^{\frac{2}{3}} $ for $ 1 \leq i \leq n$

and I'm trying to find $ min_{\Sigma x_i=G}\{max_{1\leq i \leq n}|p_i|\}  $.

In other words, if we denote $P \in \mathbb{R}^n $ s.t $ p_i = ax_{i}+bx_{i}^{\frac{2}{3}} $, I want to minimize the infinty norm of $ P $, under the constraint of $ \Sigma x_i=G $ and $x_i \geq 0$.

I want to have a close expression and not a numeric approach.
I have tried to solve this in many different ways, starting from lagrange multipliers and trying to proove this is an NP-hard problem (as a polynomial system), and I couldn't.
Any help - solution or a reference will be appreciate.

Comment: What do you know about $a$ and $b$

Comment: I may assume there are positive rational numbers

Comment: I think that better is consider a function $$h(x) =\max_{1\leq i\leq n} p_i^2 $$ since $h(x)$ attains minimum at $x_0 $  if and only if $$t(x)=\max_{1\leq i\leq n} |p_i | $$  attains minimum at $x_0 $

Comment: Why do you need the absolute value? If $x_i\geq 0$ by constraint, if $a_i,b_i\geq 0$ by assumption, then the absolute values are inactive, because all of the $p_i$ values are positive. So the model is convex.

Comment: You're going to have to accept the _very_ likely possibility that you have to compute this numerically.

Comment: can I find some formal proof that it is impossible to find a close expression?